Exercise 6.6.3 Weibel--Induced conjugation action compatible with the $G$-module structure
This is an exercise in Weibel "Homological Algebra", chapter 6 on group cohomology. For reference, this is on Page 183.
So the question was asking us to prove:
Let $A$ be a $G$-module, and form the split extension
$$
0\rightarrow A \rightarrow A\rtimes G \rightarrow G\rightarrow 1
$$
Show that the induced action of $G$ on $A$ agrees with the $G$-module structure.
Here the induced action of $G$ on $A$ is $gag^{-1}$ of $a$ in $A\rtimes G$.
I attempted the following: pick any $g\in G$ and $a\in A$, then by the definition of induced action we have
$$
(0,g)* (a, 0) = (0+ gag^{-1}, 0) = (gag^{-1}, 0),
$$
which is $gag^{-1}$ when restricted to $A$, I just don't see how this equals to $ga$.
Also how do we show in this case $g(a_1+a_2) = ga_1 + ga_2$?

Alright let me give an attempt, but please correct me if I'm wrong:

compatibility with $G$-module structure: note by the definition of semi-direct product, we have that
$$
(a,1)\cdot (0,g) = (a,g), \quad (0,g)\cdot (a,1) = (ga,a),
$$
so that in $A\rtimes G$, since $G$ acts on $A$ by conjugation, if we denote $*$ for this action,
$$
(0,g) * (a,1) = (0,g)\cdot (a,1)\cdot (0, g)^{-1} = (ga,a)\cdot (0, g^{-1}) = (ga, ag^{-1})
$$
but when this got restricted to $A$, we got $ga$, and this is exactly what we desired.

$g(a_1+a_2) = ga_1+ga_2$: I think I confused two things at a time: the $G$-modules actions were given, i.e. a priori we are given a fixed map $\mu: G\times A\rightarrow A$ which is additive in the sense that $g(a_1+a_2) = ga_1+ga_2$. But here the action of $g$ on $a$ is the induced action in $A\rtimes G$. So it's not necessarily guaranteed that $*$ as defined satisfies additivity (if we attempt to view $A\rtimes G$ as a $G$ module), although we just see in 1) that it's compatible with the given $G$-module structure.


